# Deploy to heroku : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, express

I have deployed mean stack api angular 6 to heroku , when I open the app on browser its displays brank page ,

In my server.js this is what i have

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = require('./app/config/database');

// Connect To Database
mongoose.connect(db.database);

// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to database '+db.database);
});

// On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Database error: '+err);
});

const app = express();

const movies = require('./app/routes/movies');

// Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/movies-client/dist')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/movies', movies);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/movies-client/dist/movies-client/index.html'));
});
// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

when I run `heroku logs` ,  this is what I have

```
2018-06-20T11:27:14.549707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com request_id=f44c5f42-2bd0-42de-8a5d-18551c306fd0 fwd="212.91.22.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=50ms status=200 bytes=1191 protocol=https
2018-06-20T11:27:15.041658+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/runtime.js" host=damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com request_id=197ccaba-2fa8-42d6-8293-bc481fdf3fc3 fwd="212.91.22.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=1191 protocol=https
2018-06-20T11:27:15.313302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/styles.js" host=damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com request_id=46f87c24-9a16-4d45-82e0-295b184dceec fwd="212.91.22.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1191 protocol=https
2018-06-20T11:27:16.017486+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/polyfills.js" host=damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com request_id=7dd4bb06-ce65-472b-a8d3-106882666a11 fwd="212.91.22.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=1191 protocol=https
2018-06-20T11:27:16.015745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/main.js" host=damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com request_id=1ec5edd6-632d-4b37-9984-fd076fe9a083 fwd="212.91.22.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=1191 protocol=https
2018-06-20T11:27:16.575143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/vendor.js" host=damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com request_id=94178235-0013-49e6-aaa9-d34b84cc78ef fwd="212.91.22.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1191 protocol=https
```

when I inspect the browser this error is shown :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

[image]

structre of the client app where I have dist files
[image]

why am I getting this error? and how can I solve it? any help or suggestion will be helpfully

Comment: HTML in a js file?

Comment: From error, it seems your server URL conflagrations are not correct. They are not returning right requests. Lemme check that in details.

Comment: @Teemu what do u mean?

Comment: I guess the problem is with wildcard * in your html file configurations.

Comment: your app is returning index.html file on every file request (including JS) because of it.

Comment: so how can I solve that? am new to all this :( I need help

Comment: Do these JS files exists inside `dist` folder? I am not sure about the directory structure of your statics folder.

Comment: Yes all of them

Comment: Try changing your * to / in .html file URL configurations. If it throws 404 on JS files then you need to change your js file configurations.

Comment: ok done that : now i get this error? 5Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: @RehanUmar here is the link to the page if you would like to see the error : https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana now correct the path to JS files and your this problem will be resolved. Or post the directory structure of static folder in the question for debugging purpose.

Comment: thanks rehan solve the issue, problem was in app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/movies-client/dist')));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for start debugging your app try to replace wildcard by a slash because wildcard can override `/movies` route

And may be your path

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/movies-client/dist')));
```

is wrong it seems to be

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/movies-client/dist/movies-client')));
```

Comment: I have another question, https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/ data from server api are not loaded, my locahost to see the data I use: locahost:8000/movies/movies , what do I need to change to load those files ?

Comment: It might be the wildcard route you can try to reuse wildcard instead of slash and your api url will be /movies and you can follow this tutorial I think it can be useful https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Comment: inside your api prefix all your routes with /api to not be in conflict with your app router

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to deploy to Heroku.

1. index.html -
2. server.js - app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
3. package.json changes as recommended