# NodeJs app on Heroku displays blank page after deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, mlab

I have a  [nodejs app](https://sheltered-spire-71661.herokuapp.com/) (NodeJs+ React+ MongoDb) deployed on **`heroku`** . I am connecting to **`mongoDb`** database using **`mLab`** , when i run npm start from heroku console it says **`App listening on PORT: 47147`** and **`mongoose connection successfull`** . But when i take the app (https://sheltered-spire-71661.herokuapp.com) It displays nothing . What may be the reason ? Any help is appreciated .

Adding the screenshot of the heroku console

[image]

and log

[image]

### **UPDATE**

FYI i run the **`Heroku`** app in local , and it works perfect without any problem . I don't know the problem when deploying in **`Heroku`** . Screenshot below

[image]

## **UPDATE 2**

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>LMS</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-tabs@2/style/react-tabs.css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-big-calendar@0.19.0/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8ff98e4aea.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.7.7/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i have index.html like this in **`Heroku`** , its throwing me an error in console like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I thought its failing to understand the index.html file and i changed the bundle loader script like **`<script type="text/babel" src="/bundle.js"></script>`**

The error is gone but displaying blank page . Further i thought **`its not properly serving the static assets`** from this SO question [Deploy to heroku : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947450/deploy-to-heroku-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) . Then i taken view page source and checked files from the browser 
    
and

```
<script src="/assets/javascript.js"></script>
```

and it was showing the code (https://my.herokuapp.com/assets/style.css and https://my.herokuapp.com/assets/javascript.js is working) . But when i access **`/bundle.js`** its redirecting back to the heroku app , unlike in local its showing the bundle js code . Express is serving static files like

```
//Landing
  app.get("/", autoRedirect, function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
  });
//Public files <this needs to stay right below app.get("/")!!!!
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
```

Is it a problem of **`Heroku doesnt understand the bundle.js file`** ? I went to the Heroku app console and built the app once more with **`npm run build`** and the bundle.js is generated successfully , that also didn't made any changes to the app loader .

Comment: May be delete and redeploy as it says here at the bottom of page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab

Comment: Why need to delete the app ? It can redeploy from the git itself  .

Comment: May be something got corrupted during upload, but not sure..

Comment: If its there will be error in the application log right ?

Comment: Not always sometimes no error, can you try with something simpler later key a text file or an image..